# Mongoose connection printing out both console.log when mongo server not running

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a mongoose connection to a mongodb server. When the server is running and it tries to connect it works fine and only prints out the single statement to the console. But when I haven't turned the mongo server on yet it prints both statements in the order they are in the code. I know this is not a huge error but would like to not have the health check show up as 'up' when the server is actually down.

**Mongoose connection code:**

```
mongoose.connect(config.db, {autoReconnect: true}, () => console.log('MongoDB has connected successfully.'));
mongoose.connection.on('error', function() {
  console.error('MongoDB Connection Error. Make sure MongoDB is running.');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `connect` callback receives an `error` parameter you can check:

```
mongoose.connect(config.db, {autoReconnect: true}, (err) => {
    if (!err) console.log('MongoDB has connected successfully.');
});
```

You can also separately handle the 'connect' event in the same way you're handling the 'error' event:

```
mongoose.connection.on('connect', function() {
  console.error('MongoDB has connected successfully');
});
```

Comment: With mongoose 6.6.5, at least, the connection event is `mongoose.connection.on('connected', ...)`, not `connect`.